# How to manage Spring batch parallel processing write method calls for PDF generation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, parallel-processing, spring-batch

My project having Spring batch process where it should generate one PDF containing multiple data. The structure of the system for now is defined in three steps of Spring batch, where in the `reader` its reading one PostgresSQL query from where its getting data. In the `processor` there only few validations not much more and its return the same object to writer. Now in `writer` I tried to generate a single PDF containing all multiple data which writer method received. I have configured `SimpleTaskExecutor` by specifying `concurrency limit` as 20 which means it will use the multiple thread to do batch processing. Now What is happening from the query defined in reader return 4 data, and its going on processor to writer. When it calls write method its calling 4 times, at same moment. So, now what's happening that while generating PDF at a time its only might have single data, because its `running parallelly` and the data is not coming in sequential method which is expected.

Below is my bit piece of code,

```
@Component
public class Writer implements ItemWriter<PeopleDecoded> {

    @Autowired
    private PersonDecodedRepository personDecodedRepository;

    @Autowired
    PDFGeneratorService service;

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends PeopleDecoded> items) throws Exception {
        items.stream().map(peopleDecoded -> {
            File pdf = service.createPDF(peopleDecoded);
            peopleDecoded.setFile(pdf.toBytes());
           return peopleDecoded;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
        personDecodedRepository.saveAll(items);
    }
}
```

As the above write method calls at the same time for all 4 data, its not able write all data into single PDF. I tried different ways like to take a `ConcurrentHashMap` but nothing is meaningful due to parallel processing. I also tried to take one `OutputStream` and tried to write over there but also not worked. As the data can be large I would required to do parallel processing instead of sequential, but having this difficulties. Any kind of help of even other suggestions or alternative will be appreciated. Thanks in advance to all.

Comment: I don't understand the correlation between the large data size and the need to process in parallel? Because when it is finally written to PDF, it must be sequential. If the data to be processed is d1, d2, d3, d4,...., because of parallel processing, the order of writing may be d2, d8, d12, d1, d4, d3...., the order of such data is in Is PDF acceptable? If not, it means that your data must still be sequential when writing to PDF.

Comment: That won't work. What do you think happens if 4 threads write on the same file? Ever tried writing with 4 people on the same piece of paper and make it readable?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @life888888, what I want to make here is if I do parallel the time to do gather data, process it will save and if there is larger data comes and if its processed parallelly then might be it will save some amount of time.

Comment: @M.Deinum, respecting your answer, and I am also bit not sure that this will work as parallel, do you have any other suggestion to make it flexible in terms less execution time?

Comment: Your writing is always single threaded, so I doubt there is anything you can do to speed it up. The majority of the time will, probably, be spend writing so trying to optimize the read will not really help.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @M.Deinum, I got your point.